# find the derivative of $f(x)=\frac1x+2$ using definition of the derivative

Tags: derivatives

I am struggling to find the derivative of $f(x)=\frac1x+2$ (and/or $f(x)=\frac1{x+2}$) using the definition of the derivative. thank you

Comment: Do you know the definition?

Comment: Is that meant to be $\frac1x + 2$ or $\frac{1}{x+2}$?

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer , the second part you wrote is what I am asking, 1/x+2

Answer (score 4):

- First case

$$f'(x):=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}   \right)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(
\frac{-h}{x(x+h)}\right)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}
\frac{-1}{x(x+h)}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

- Second case

$$f'(x):=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{1}{x+2+h}-\frac{1}{x+2}   \right)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(
\frac{-h}{(x+2)(x+2+h)}\right)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}
\frac{-1}{(x+2)(x+2+h)}=-\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}$$

Comment: For the second function the strategy is similar: once you write the difference in the definition of the derivative explicitly you arrive at a single fraction $\frac{-1}{(x+2)(x+2+h)}$, whose limit for $h\rightarrow 0$ is $\frac{-1}{(x+2)^2}$.

Comment: Edit: comment moved to the answer

Comment: You are welcome!